# Handle React re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a similar situation like the one in the sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-fs0em

Basically what I want to achieve is that `Table.tsx` is my base component and `App` component is acting like a wrapper component. I am returning the JSX from the wrapper file.

Everything is fine but the problem is whenever I hover over any `name`, `getData()` is called and that is too much rerendering. Here it is a simple example but in my case, in real, the records are more.

**Basically `Table` is a generic component which can be used by any other component and the data to be displayed in can vary. For e.g. rn `App` is returning `name` and `image`. Some other component can use the `Table.tsx` component to display `name`, `email`, and `address`. Think of `App` component as a wrapper.**

How can I avoid this `getData()` to not to be called again and again on hover?

Can I use `useMemo` or what approach should I use to avoid this?

Please help

Comment: Invoking callback !== rerender, though in this case it is since you return *new* JSX. You can create a throttled the `getData` handler and pass that instead. It is only getting called one though on enter and leave, but I'm not really sure what you're going for here. The element in `Table.jsx` should handle its own hover style versus expecting some callback. Perhaps we need more context around your *actual* use-case.

Comment: Do not worry unless it is causing performance issues. Preemptive optimisation will cause more trouble than it solves. We must also remember that a React re-render does not equal a DOM re-render.

Comment: Why do you need to call data for every hover in the first place? It might be better not to render inside a "get data" function.

Comment: It’s common to load data in a useEffect and not return a component inside that function. What’s the purpose of keeping index in state? What’s your actual goal here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have updated the sandbox, please have a look. Basically Table is a generic component which can be used by any other component and the data to displayed in can vary. For e.g. rn I am sending name and image. Some other component can use the Table component to display name, email, and address. Think of App component as a wrapper. How can I achieve the same thing differently if I dont return the component from a function?

Comment: @DrewReese sorry I missed your comment. I explained the whole scenario in my last comment. Can you please go through that and if still sth is not clear. I ll explain it further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you update the "hover" index state in `Table.jsx` it rerenders, i.e. the entire table it mapped again. This also is regenerating the table row JSX each time, thus why you see the log "getData called!" so much.

You've effectively created your own list renderer, and `getData` is your "renderRow" function. IMO `Table` shouldn't have any state and the component being rendered via `getData` should handle its own hover state.

Create *some* "row component", i.e. the *thing* you want to render per element in the data array, that handles it's own hover state, so when updating state it *only* rerenders itself.

```
const RowComponent = ({ index, name }) => {
  const [hov, setHov] = useState();

  return (
    <div
      key={name}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHov(index)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHov(undefined)}
      style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}
    >
      <div> {name} </div>
      <div>
        <img
          src={hov === index ? img2 : img1}
          height="30px"
          width="30px"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Table.jsx should now only take a `data` prop and a callback function to render a specific element, `getData`.

```
interface Props {
  data: string[];
  getData: () => JSX.Element;
}

export const Table: React.FC<Props> = ({ data, getData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((name: string, index: number) => getData(name, index))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

App

```
function App() {
  const data = ["Pete", "Peter", "John", "Micheal", "Moss", "Abi"];

  const getData = (name: string, index: number, hov: number) => {
    console.log("getData called!", index);
    return <RowComponent name={name} index={index} />;
  };

  return <Table data={data} getData={getData} />;
}
```

[image: Edit React Typescript renderRow example]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Can I use `useMemo` or `useCallback` so that the `getData()` function is not called again and again on hover change? Is it possible?

Comment: @newbie Is `getData` being called more than once for you in my sandbox? I see it called only on mount of the table. You *could* use `useCallback`, but since it's only called when `Table` needs to rerender (because `data` updated) I don't see any advantage to doing that as `App` doesn't rerender because it has no state and takes no props, i.e. `getData` is never redefined. The hover change has been abstracted *into* the row component.

Comment: No, it is called just once in your sandbox but I am asking in my sandbox. Is there a way I can use `useCallback` in my sandbox to avoid `getData` from calling again and again on hover?

Comment: The only problem with your approach is for e.g. I am using `Table` component thrice and each time `getData()` return different JSX. In this case, I have to make a `RowComponent` each time to handle hover and other stuff. Would not that be duplication? I am sorry I am very new to ReactJS so apologies for any naive comments

Comment: @newbie "Is there a way I can use useCallback in my sandbox to avoid getData from calling again and again on hover?" No, I don't think so, for the reason I explained. `getData` is never redefined since `App` never updates. `useCallback` is used to memoize a callback so it is a stable reference, and `useMemo` is to memoize a value. Because `getData` is already stable `useCallback` won't do anything, and because it's only called when it *needs* to return new JSX `useMemo` won't work either.

Comment: @newbie If each instance of your `Table` uses a different "row renderer" then you'll need to specify each "row render" callback. If a concern about code duplication is the "hovering" logic then using a wrapper or Higher Order Component here is a good design pattern. You can abstract the "is hovered" state there and pass an "is hovered" prop to the "row element".

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. Just one last thing if you could suggest some reading links where I can learn the thing you mentioned in your last comment about using a wrapper or Higher Order Component.

Comment: @newbie https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement and  https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html